# Combining koa-router with koa-handlebar

Tags: template-engine, koa

I am trying to use koa-handlebars (a server-side templating engine) with koa-routers in koa.

```
.get('/', function* () {
    this.body = this.render('myViewHere', {});
})
```

There is no documentation on this!

The only documentation is this:

```
app.use(function* () {
    yield this.render('myViewHere', {});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the middleware on the router for it to work.

```
// more code above...
var handlebars = require("koa-handlebars");
var router = require('koa-router');

var myRouter = new router(); 

myRouter.use(handlebars({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));

myRouter.get('/', function* () {
    yield this.render('myView', {});
})
// more code below...
```

Comment: Is there any other way to render without using it on the router middleware ?

Comment: @h4ck3d Yes there is! Located in the example in the following link (under `usage`) :) https://github.com/dominicbarnes/koa-handlebars

Comment: But that will render it for all routes

Comment: @h4ck3d You never said anything about rendering for specific routes :) You need a router if you wish to render for specific routes (thats what a router does)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suggest you to use koa-ejs with koa. it's relatively supported module, which easy to use.

You can use koa-hbs, but you will encounter issues when using it with partials.